# Завернуть все слова в span JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

```
$('#text:contains(" ")').each(function() {
     this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/(.*)/,'<span>$1</span>');
});
```

Мой пример не работает, меняет только некоторые слова.

Comment: В чем смысл использования `.each()`, если `$('#text:contains(" ")')` всегда содержит 0 или 1 DOM элемент? Это первый момент. Второй момент - необходим соответствующий HTML код, демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас неправильное регурлярное выражение.

Выражение `(.*)` значит любыой символ, 0 или больше раз.

По-моему, хотите выражение `/(\S+)/`, которое значит любой символ, кроме символов пробела, 1 или больше раз.

Тоже надо добавить флаг `g`, чтобы завернуть все слова, а не только первое.

Вот пример кода. Добавил css, чтобы было видно, где находятся элементов `<span>`.

```js
var textDiv = $('#text:contains(" ")');
if (textDiv.length) {
  textDiv.html(textDiv.html().replace(/(\S+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'));
}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">Привет! Как у тебя дела? ¡Hola! ¿Cómo estás? Hello, how are you?</div>
```

**Исправление**: [как sepgg отметил в его ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429784/176684), надо использовать `+` вместо `*` в этом случае.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ выше почти правильный!
`*` в `/(\S*)/` означает, что будет выбрано 0 или больше не пробельных символов, т.е. если посмотреть на результат то пробелы тоже обернулись в `<span>` вместо `*` поставьте `+` будут выбираться 1 или более непробельных символов.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').html($('#text').text().replace(/(\S+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'));
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">Привет! Как у тебя дела? ¡Hola! ¿Cómo estás? Hello, how are you?</p>

<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: А не подскажете: как сделать так, чтобы только символы, без знаков вопроса и т.п.? Что-то я до сих пор никак не сделаю.

Comment: ([A-Za-z]+)|([А-Яа-я]+) - так правильно ли будет?

Comment: Ну да. /([A-Za-zа-яА-Я]+)/g, но тут будут проблема с умляутами, если таковые имеются в тексте, типа этого Cómo estás